# why is phpunit not taking directory which have a underscore '_'

Tags: php, phpunit

My command:

```
phpunit --log-junit /log/unitreport.xml --coverage-clover /log/result.xml --coverage-    html /log/coverage /sites/all/modules/delete_shopping_cart/
```

Files to test which are in the directory:

delete_shopping_cart_Test.php
another_Test.php

Output:

```
Cannot open file "/sites/all/modules/delete/shopping/cart/.php"
```

why is phpunit taking the '_" of the directory and treating it as a '/' ?

how do I change this so that it goes to the correct location.

Comment: What are the names of the test class and the tested class? Do you use any autoloader?

Answer (score 1):

Autoloaders tend to treat underscores as separate directories:

```
A_B_C
```

becomes

```
+- A
|  +- B
|  |  +- C
```

Comment: Not correct. When using namespaces, underscores in the class name remain as they are (in the PSR-0 standard)! Only when there are no backslashes in the class name, all underscores are converted to directory separators - but this seems to be the case here.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, that Namespaces do retain the underscore if the PSR-0 standard is being used.  However, not every auto loader or module is PSR-0 compliant.

Comment: I am still confused. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Do not use an auto-loader and require the file, or change the class name to remove the underscores.

Comment: For me the file is being included without an autolaoder, but PhpUnit still converts the underscores to directories. PhpUntit should not be enforcing a specific code style that cannot be customized.